# Is there any locking of cases or delay in CRUD operations after updating case assignment rules?

Tags: case, assignment-rules, locking

If I update case assignment rules are there any locking or differences such as query delays that I should consider?

The documentation does not specifically list update assignment rule considerations in regards to performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Case assignment rules run synchronously within the DML transaction where they are "triggered" (e.g. Case insert/update where the [DmlOptions header](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Database_AssignmentRuleHeader.htm?search_text=assignment) to run assignment rules) is set.  This header is automatically set, for example, in Email-to-Case or Web-to-Case. See [Triggers and Order of Execution Step 8](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm?search_text=order%20of%20execution)
- When the assignment rules run, they update the Case with a new `Ownerid`. This is a DML operation. [Triggers will re-execute](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33485/do-assignment-rule-owner-updates-cause-update-triggers-to-fire), if any, on the Case object

If there is any contention, it would be from other transactions on the Case object running concurrently that, perhaps are locking a common resource such as a parent Account or Contact. There is nothing *per se* special about assignment rules versus workflow field updates or Process Builder record updates

Comment: Thanks for the information. So there is no recalculation time or any consideration along those lines that would need to be considered for updating a case assignment rule during business hours?

Comment: If you update a case assignment rule; the new rule takes effect on the very next transaction that needs to run assignment rules. Assignment rules don't run in the background

Comment: Thanks, I was concerned about some sort of similar recalculation performance degradation that I have seen in updating sharing rules.

Comment: yep - sharing rules run in background as does recalculating Roll up summaries, Shield encryption, ... but not assignment rules or auto-response rules or escalation rules